# Conditional compilation of same source as a 32 and 64 bit application

Tags: c++, windows, 32bit-64bit, conditional-compilation

We have a 32-bit windows application which uses C++ and good old Windows application model. Is it technically possible to have a single source and compile it as 32 and 64 bit by say turning a compiler switch or using some macros?

Currently I don't think the code will compile as a 64-bit application, I'll have to fix the compilation errors, in general how should I proceed so that it compiles as both 64&32 bit app. What should I keep in mind? What will be the challenges? Any comments and tips will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: To answer your first question, yes, there are compiler flags you can use that turn on compilation for 64 or 32-bit. What the flags are and how you pass them in depends on the compiler.

Comment: It really depends on what your application is doing with respect to hardware-specific code and any surface areas that it shares with other binaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning "**What should I keep in mind? What will be the challenges?**" These are most common issues that I've encountered when porting code from 32-bit to 64-bit:

- Assuming that a pointer is 4-bytes
- Assuming that sizeof(int) == sizeof(pointer)
- Assuming that sizeof(int) == sizeof(size_t)
- Inline / hard coded x86 assembly

Make sure you use the most strict warning level when compiling (`/W4` on microsoft's compiler or `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` on gcc) to help catch conversions from a larger type to a smaller type.

Here is Microsoft's [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384214.aspx) for porting, but is appropriate for other compilers as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and guide for porting.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers define macros depending on their target platform. For example, GCC defines `__i386__` and `__amd64__`, and MSVC defines `_M_IX86` and `_M_X64` for 32-bit and 64-bit, respectively. You can use these macros, for example, in you preprocessor `#ifdef` statements to direct the flow of compilation.

There is an excellent source on [Pre-defined C/C++ Compiler Macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) for different compilers.

Comment: But why would you need them?

Comment: @JamesKanze Compiler macros in general or macros defined for 32/64-bit platforms specifically?.. What if I want to use some inline assembler, for example?

Comment: The 32/64 bit macros specifically.  (For inline assembler: there isn't any in the Microsoft 64 bit compiler.)

Comment: Well, we are not limited to Microsoft compilers, thankfully ;). But specifically for Microsoft, what if I want to use functions that fill in [CONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284(v=vs.85).aspx) structure for some, say, stack tracing? There are things that architecture dependable.

Comment: Most of what's architecture dependent should be in a separate module, and you pick up the correct implementation by means of the paths and filenames you pass the compiler, not by means of `#ifdef` etc.

Comment: I am writing a stack tracing library on Windows. I want it to work for 32/64 bit versions. I have two implementation headers - one for 32bit, another for 64 -bit. I have a single "interface" header that includes either of those via `#ifdef`. What's wrong with that? I don't want the user of the library to worry about different headers...

Comment: Using an #ifdef to control which header you include is probably not a problem, especially if it's a header which the user needs to include.

Comment: Well, then we agree that we can use `#ifdef` with 32-/64-bit macros to pick up the correct implementation? I'm confused now as to where we disagree... Maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted to use the `#ifdef` to wrap code or declarations.  In an application, you probably have no use for `#ifdef` et al. except for include guides, since if you have system dependent code, you'll need to put it into separate source files anyway.  In the case of a library, as you say, you may not want to burden the client with the extra `/I` (although my libraries do).  In which case, you need some `#ifdef` in a single header, which defines the paths to the dependent includes.  (Or use the pimpl idiom, so there aren't any dependencies in the client hdrs.)

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible, since we do it.  The hardest part is
getting Visual Studios configured for x64 (and that's not really
that difficult).  Other than that, there's nothing special, at
least if the C++ is the least bit clean (and even if it's
not).  The exact same sources work for both; no conditional
compilation or whatever needed.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem while porting should be different sizeof() for various types here and there. So that, pieces of code which run correctly on 32 bit, may cause time-bomb effect on 64 bit. For example, you can have some code like that:

```
size_t sz = GetSomethingBig();
DWORD dw = (DWORD)sz;
```

So, at 32 bit both types, size_t and DWORD, have the same size (4 bytes). At ported version, size_t will be 8 bytes long while DWORD still the same. As we do raw C-style typecast, no compilation error follows. And at runtime, everything is OK if sz is less than 0x100000000. All other values will cause data loss, with hard-to-predict effects.